# Group part of equation so that it looks better

Tags: spacing, equations

When LaTeX compiles this it looks terrible. The processors spaces the equation so it does not look like it needs to for my purposes.

Here is the code...

```
\begin{displaymath}
E[W_{A}^{s_2}] = \underbrace{\underbrace{E[N_{A}^{s_2}]}_{\mbox{\tiny 
 Number of waiting class $A$ jobs}} \cdot     
 \underbrace{E[X_2]}_{\mbox{\tiny Mean service time at  
 \$s_2$}}}_{\mbox{Mean time needed to serve the
  customers ahead in the queue}} + 
  \underbrace{E[R_{A}^{s_2}]}_{\mbox{\tiny Unfinished work at $s_2$}}
\end{displaymath}
```

What I want is the `\underbrace{E[N_{A}^{s_2}]}_{\mbox{\tiny Number of waiting \\ class $A$ jobs}} \cdot \underbrace{E[X_2]}_{\mbox{\tiny Mean service time at $s_2$}}` part of the equation to be very close to each other.

How can I do this?

Thanks.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Maybe you liked:

[image]

As can be seen, the long text of under braces are broken into more lines by use of `substack` provided by `amsmath` (or `mathtools` which call `amsmath`):

```
\documentclass[preview, margin=3mm]{standalone}
\usepackage{mathtools}

\begin{document}
\[
E[W_{A}^{s_2}]
    = \underbrace{%
    \underbrace{E[N_{A}^{s_2}]}_{\substack{\text{Number of}\\ 
                                           \text{ waiting class}\\ 
                                           \text{$A$ jobs}}} 
    \cdot
    \underbrace{E[X_2]}_{\substack{\text{Mean service}\\
                                   \text{time at $s_2$}}}
                 }_{\substack{\text{Mean time needed}\\
                              \text{to serve the customers}\\ 
                              \text{ ahead in the queue}}}
    + 
    \underbrace{E[R_{A}^{s_2}]}_{\substack{\text{Unfinished}\\ 
                                           \text{work at $s_2$}}}
\]
\end{document}
```

Comment: Perfect! This looks great! Thanks for your help